# How to set cookies in browser

Tags: express, cookies, vite, mern, setcookie

I am working on a MERN(MongoDB atlas, Express, React typescript, node.js) project. I am not able to set cookies in my browser. I am receiving the cookies in network tab of the browser developer tool. but the same are not being set to the memory. there is some issues related to security. I have tried the same thing with google chrome and firefox.
code snippet is attached.
` res.cookie( COOKIE_NAME, userToken,{
path:"/",
domain:"127.0.0.1",
expires,
httpOnly:true,
signed:true,
sameSite:"none",
[image]secure:false

```
  })`
```

I tried using the sameSite :"none" and "localhost". Same way i have tried other changes with secure also.
firefox is also causing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I almost sure that you forgot to include credentials in your auth query.

Example with axios:

```
await axios.post(
    'http://localhost:5000/login',
    { data: loginData },
    { withCredentials: true }
)
```