# Cookie is not being set in browser, with res.cookie()

Tags: express, cookies

I am trying to set JWT token to cookie in browser from backend with `res.cookie()`, but it is not being set.
While testing the same API in postman it has been set to cookie.

I try to set it with frontend and it is set in cookies.

Comment: Can you share your response from browser, please? You can also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77632596/22912119